# Update several select in MySQL

Tags: mysql, database, jira

It's a sample to see the result.

Hello Everyone,
I wrote a query as a sample and I used several selects because I needed to add columns separately.
So, I got the result.
now I want to know if can I use an update statement for this query?

```
select T3.*,ao_00b950_aoproject_value.VALUE ODP from
(select T2.*,ao_00b950_aoproject_value.VALUE SOD from 
(select T1.*,ao_00b950_aoproject_value.VALUE Platform from (SELECT project.LEAD,project.id,project.pname,project.pkey,ao_00b950_aoproject_value.VALUE Status FROM jira820db.project
LEFT JOIN jira820db.ao_00b950_aoproject_value 
on project.ID=ao_00b950_aoproject_value.PROJECT_ID 
and ao_00b950_aoproject_value.FIELD_ID =1) as T1
left join ao_00b950_aoproject_value
on T1.ID = ao_00b950_aoproject_value.project_ID
and ao_00b950_aoproject_value.field_ID=26) as T2
left join ao_00b950_aoproject_value
on T2.ID = ao_00b950_aoproject_value.project_ID
and ao_00b950_aoproject_value.field_ID=28) as T3
left join ao_00b950_aoproject_value
on T3.ID = ao_00b950_aoproject_value.project_ID
and ao_00b950_aoproject_value.field_ID=27
```

So, I wrote this update statement:

```
update
(select T3.*,ao_00b950_aoproject_value.VALUE ODP from
(select T2.*,ao_00b950_aoproject_value.VALUE SOD from 
(select T1.*,ao_00b950_aoproject_value.VALUE Platform from (SELECT project.LEAD,project.id,project.pname,project.pkey,ao_00b950_aoproject_value.VALUE Status FROM jira820db.project
LEFT JOIN jira820db.ao_00b950_aoproject_value 
on project.ID=ao_00b950_aoproject_value.PROJECT_ID 
and ao_00b950_aoproject_value.FIELD_ID =1) as T1
left join ao_00b950_aoproject_value
on T1.ID = ao_00b950_aoproject_value.project_ID
and ao_00b950_aoproject_value.field_ID=26) as T2
left join ao_00b950_aoproject_value
on T2.ID = ao_00b950_aoproject_value.project_ID
and ao_00b950_aoproject_value.field_ID=28) as T3
left join ao_00b950_aoproject_value
on T3.ID = ao_00b950_aoproject_value.project_ID
and ao_00b950_aoproject_value.field_ID=27) as ww
set project.LEAD = 'kami'
where project.ID ='10000';
```

But unfortunately, it's not working and I'm not surprised because I'm not an expert in MySQL.
Does anybody have any suggestions?
Or I'm writing wrong the code like always.
With the first query, I get my result, and run perfectly.
With the second one, I get an error code 1288 "The target table ww of the UPDATE is not updatable".

Comment: Your SELECT is not updatable.

Comment: Please add table definitions, sample data and expected outcome as text.